# Vote any one team through application and one user can vote only single time in a day

Tags: php

There is an application regarding Cricket Tournament there are few teams in that tournament . we can vote any one team through application and one user can vote only single time in a day How can be possible ,just share logic and thoughts.

Comment: create database table to hold voted users and timestamp, then check against it before letting user to vote. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do it with db.

In the DB u should create a table with columns like-

```
votes(
         user_id,
         team_id,
         date,
         ......,
         unique (user_id, team_id, date)
     )
```

Then if a user gives vote, u should store votes here.
**Look carefully** there is a unique field in the database on ***user_id***, team_id and ***date***.

SO only one vote for one team by a user in a day can be possible.

Before storing a vote, u should check if there is a vote for the team by he user in that day already.

- If yes, then u should not store the vote.
- If no, then u should store the vote.

It will work for u.